# Illustrating symmetric key distribution

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams, svg, tikz-datavisualization

Can I draw something like this programmatically with LaTeX?

I drew these with Adobe Illustrator, but it gets pretty time-consuming.
Even with relatively few nodes. What it attempts to demonstrate is the number of "symmetric" cryptographic keys required for secure communication between ***n*** parties - for which the formula is ***n(n-1)/2*** (I tried to render that with LaTeX/MathJax, but it won't let me for some reason).

[image]

And it's hard to get it perfect. It's always off by a small amount, as you can see here. It might not seem like much but with a lot of nodes, it can add up and skew the output, and cause problems when trying to get everything to fit properly.

[image]

I wanted to draw a big one with up up to 100 nodes, so it would be best if I could do it programmatically, rather than having to type up several hundred lines of code manually. Is that kind of thing possible with LaTeX? I heard someone say TeX is a full Turing complete programming language. If that's true, I'm not sure, but it would probably make it pretty useful for generating diagrams with this kind of data, kinda like [D3.js](https://d3js.org/).

As you can see, by the time you get to 10 or 11 vertices, it can be pretty unruly:

[image]

Comment: After all, 100 vertices is *a lot*. How are you going to arrange vertices?

Comment: @Symbol1 Same as I have been, probably. Around. A circle or a polygon. Doesn't necessarily have to be 100 vertices, I want to be able to specify an arbitrary number, and produce a graph with that many interconnected nodes. In a similar fashion to what I've drawn. I experimented with your GitHub code and got it to do some cool things, but I was just hacking around, manipulating values, not really understanding a lot of it.

Comment: Consider accepting the provided answer since it seems to answer your question.

Comment: @tjt263 Would you mind sharing in which context you're going to use it?

Comment: The same is true for some of your other questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\newcounter{pft}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,pics/cgram/.style={code={
\foreach \XX [count=\YY starting from 0] in {1,...,#1}
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\LstCols}[\YY]}
\node[circle,draw,minimum size=2.5em,fill=\mycolor] (c-#1-\XX) at 
({{\LstAngles}[#1-2]-\YY*360/#1}:1.5) {\setcounter{pft}{\XX}\Alph{pft}};}
\foreach \XX [evaluate=\XX as \Ymax using {int(\XX-1)}] in {2,...,#1}
{\foreach \YY  in {1,...,\Ymax}
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolorA}{{\LstCols}[\XX-1]}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolorB}{{\LstCols}[\YY-1]}
\path (c-#1-\XX) -- (c-#1-\YY) coordinate[pos=0.1] (aux0) coordinate[pos=0.9] (aux1);
\fill[black] (aux0) to[bend left=2] (aux1) to[bend left=2] (aux0);
\draw[{Stealth[fill=\mycolorB,length=7pt,inset=2pt]}-{Stealth[fill=\mycolorA,length=7pt,inset=2pt]}] (c-#1-\XX) -- (c-#1-\YY);
}}}}]
\def\LstCols{"red","orange","yellow","green!70!black","blue!70!white","purple!80!white"}
\def\LstAngles{180,150,135,128,150}
\path (-5,0) pic {cgram=2} (0,0.5) pic {cgram=3} (5,0) pic {cgram=4}
 (-3,-4) pic {cgram=5}  (3,-4) pic {cgram=6};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Zoom in:

[image]

And yes, for large numbers `N` of nodes it becomes busy, simply since the number of connections goes like `N (N-1)/2`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\definecolor{colorA}{RGB}{202, 38, 49} 
\definecolor{colorB}{RGB}{222, 146, 60} 
\definecolor{colorC}{RGB}{240, 215, 68} 
\definecolor{colorD}{RGB}{126, 183, 86} 
\definecolor{colorE}{RGB}{98, 173, 233} 
\definecolor{colorF}{RGB}{158, 76, 150}  
\newcounter{pft}
\tikzset{pics/cgram/.style={code={
\foreach \XX [count=\YY starting from 0] in {1,...,#1}
{\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\iA}{mod(\XX-1,6)+1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\LstCols}[\iA-1]}
\node[circle,draw,minimum size=2.5em,fill=\mycolor] (c-#1-\XX) at 
({-\YY*360/#1}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cgram radius}) {\setcounter{pft}{\iA}\Alph{pft}};}
\foreach \XX [evaluate=\XX as \Ymax using {int(\XX-1)}] in {2,...,#1}
{\foreach \YY  in {1,...,\Ymax}
 {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\iA}{mod(\XX-1,6)+1}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\iB}{mod(\YY-1,6)+1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolorA}{{\LstCols}[\iA-1]}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolorB}{{\LstCols}[\iB-1]}
 \draw[{Stealth[fill=\mycolorB,length=7pt,inset=2pt]}-{Stealth[fill=\mycolorA,length=7pt,inset=2pt]}] (c-#1-\XX) -- (c-#1-\YY);
}}
}},cgram radius/.initial=1.5}
\begin{document}
\foreach \Nmax in {2,4,...,40}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\draw (-11,-11) rectangle (11,11);
\def\LstCols{"colorA","colorB","colorC","colorD","colorE","colorF"}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myradius}{sqrt(2.5*\Nmax)}
\path  pic[cgram radius=\myradius] {cgram=\Nmax};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I doubt that it is necessary to use anchors. The Inscribed angle is half the arc.

Comment: @Symbol1 Sorry, what do you mean? Where am I using an anchor?

Comment: This `(c-#1-\XX)`, is what I understand as anchor. It is essentially `(c-#1.\XX)`, right?

Comment: @Symbol1 Not at all. This is just the name of the node, these are hyphens, not minuses. Note that `shapes.geometric` was not used here, and I am removing it now. (Anchors come with `.`, not `-`.)

Comment: PS just in case anybody cares about the colors, I had a bit of a play with it, and I used `"cyan"` and `"violet!80!magenta!70"` (or something like that), instead of `"blue"` and `"purple"`. The `"blue"` is pretty much indigo, so you could probably do a full spectrum (i.e. ROYGBIV) with `"red"`, `"orange"`, `"yellow"`, `"green"`, `"cyan"`, `"blue"`, `"violet"`. Also I came across a big swatch pad at over at http://latexcolor.com/ (most will require `\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}` in the preamble).

Comment: @marmot What I meant was this: [in my construction](https://gist.github.com/Symbol1/83139b91d4b2d41628bca0147e324e44), I can avoid `\LstAngles{180,150,135,128,150}` because Ti*k*Z will choose the right angle automatically.

Comment: +1: Surprisingly little code needed for that.

Comment: @Symbol1 What you propose is certainly neat but is this really what you meant by anchors? Also in your construction the orientation is different from the OP's, yours is counterclockwise while the OP's and mine are clockwise and in your code the shape with six vertices is rotated. The angles were only to reproduce the OP's screen shot.

Comment: @marmot Can you please explain your code a bit?

Comment: @tjt263 All I am doing is to declare a pic that has one argument, the number of nodes. These nodes are placed clockwise (because they are clockwise in your screen shot) equidistantly around a (virtual) circle, and filled with colors that is stored in `\LstCols`, and with letters A, B, ..... Then all nodes are connected with arrows, whereby the arrow head at a given node has the color of the node the arrow comes from. The list of angles is introduced to match the orientation of your screen shot, they determine the angle of node `A`..

Comment: @tjt263 In order to match your colors, use `\definecolor{colorA}{RGB}{202, 38, 49}
\definecolor{colorB}{RGB}{222, 146, 60}
\definecolor{colorC}{RGB}{240, 215, 68}
\definecolor{colorD}{RGB}{126, 183, 86}
\definecolor{colorE}{RGB}{98, 173, 233}
\definecolor{colorF}{RGB}{158, 76, 150}` and `\def\LstCols{"colorA","colorB","colorC","colorD","colorE","colorF"}`.

Comment: @tjt263 All you need to do then is to add some entries to the list of colors and to the list of angles, and then you can do `\path pic {cgram=N};`, where `N` is an integer.

Comment: so, if i want 100 nodes, i need to enter all the angles?

Comment: @tjt263 Not if there is a prescription what the diagram should look like. For `N=100` you need also to adjust the radius.

Comment: Maybe you could point out which pieces of code perform which function.

Comment: @marmot Never mind; I finally understand your construction.

Comment: Well my friend, this is a piece of art!

Comment: Actually, I shouldn't say the Ti*k*Z manual *sucks*. It too has a lot of good things about it. The thing is, it'd only require a tiny effort to improve it a hundredfold; to transition from barely useful to excellent. As it stands, it's barely useable despite all the good things about it. Mainly because it assumes too much prior knowledge. It's written by those with the most experience, in a style that's most applicable to them. So that's good for the 1% of us who are already experts. Not so useful for the 99% of us that actually want/need guidance. Because that's what it should do; guide us.

Comment: @tjt263 You might be interested in https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/640#issuecomment-504888430. I am working on this, but did not accomplish much so far since I have a problem that parallels yours: I do not understand how to deal with github. So I think I know how you feel. On the other hand, I feel that the situations are different in that I usually add explanations if I get asked on something specific. However, as of now I have not yet received answers to my github questions that allow me to get going. This is mostly my fault, but also the fact that I did not find a manual on this.

Comment: I have cleaned up some comments here: they don't really help to refine the answer (which ultimately is the aim of comment threads).

Answer (score 4):

So this is my construction for future references.

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz,rgb]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    /pgf/arrow keys/colorsize/.style={fill=#1,length=10pt}
}
\def\N{70}
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{sunflower}{ % #1 is the index of vertex
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunindex{#1-.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunangle{mod(\sunindex*16.18034,10)*36}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunradius{sqrt(\sunindex)*50}
    \pgfpointpolar{\sunangle}{\sunradius}
}
\globalcolorstrue
\def\definesuncolor#1{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\sunindex{#1-.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunhue{mod(\sunindex*16.18034,10)*36}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunsaturation{sqrt(\sunindex/\N)}
    \definecolor{sun#1}{Hsb}{\sunhue,\sunsaturation,1}
}
\tikz{
    \foreach\i in{1,...,\N}{
        \definesuncolor{\i}
        \path(sunflower cs:\i)node(vertex\i)
            [circle,draw,minimum size=2cm,line width=6pt]{};
        \fill[sun\i](vertex\i)+(1pt,1pt)circle(1);
    }
    \foreach\i in{2,...,\N}{
        \foreach\j in{1,...,\numexpr\i-1}{
            \path[scale=.666/sqrt(\N)]
                [shift=(vertex\i)](sunflower cs:\j)coordinate(X-\i-\j)
                [shift=(vertex\j)](sunflower cs:\i)coordinate(Y-\i-\j);
            \draw[{Stealth[colorsize=sun\j]}-{Stealth[colorsize=sun\i]}]
                [line width=.1](X-\i-\j)--(Y-\i-\j);
        }
    }
    \foreach\i in{2,...,\N}{
        \foreach\j in{1,...,\numexpr\i-1}{
            \draw[{Stealth[colorsize=sun\j]}-{Stealth[colorsize=sun\i]}]
                [dash pattern=on0off9999](X-\i-\j)--(Y-\i-\j);
        }
    }
}

\end{document}
```

Some comments to whomever wants to play with this:

- `sunflower` is the coordinate system that controls how to place vertices.
  It is the same algorithm that sunflower uses to place its seeds.
  See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helianthus_annuus#Mathematical_model_of_floret_arrangement)
- The color of each vertex is control by `\definesuncolor#1`.
  Currently it is defined such that the sunflower looks like the HSB wheel.
- There are two nested-for-loops at the end.
  The former loop draws the edge, the later loop draws the arrow tips.
- The position of arrow tip is controlled by `(X-\i-\j)` and `(Y-\i-\j)`.
  Currently they are the relative positions of the vertices.
  So the arrows tips on each vertex also looks like the HSB wheel.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh, my, that is one beautiful mess!

Comment: I doubt you need anchors here. ;-)

Comment: @marmot Good question. If I work hard enough, I should be able to define an anchorborder that works.

Comment: If  anyone's trying to count, this is 70 vertices.

Comment: Was able to do 100 nodes with LuaLaTeX.